# I need a statistical diagram which will help me depict the following data

Tags: data-visualization

I have a temperature data with respect to the land use land cover percentage.

eg:

Residential Area: 30% Land cover: 45 deg C Temperature

Water Area: 2% Land Cover: 22 deg C Temperature

and so on....

I have around 12 classes of area, and corresponding to ever class, its percentage area cover and corresponding average temperature. Percentage Area cover adds up to 100.

Comment: If the dataset is that small, you should post it all. If the residential area is really at $45^\circ$ C those people need really good air conditioning and a water supply.

Comment: Both of your variables are continuous, so why not just use an annotated scatterplot? For example, land cover percent on the X axis, temperature on the Y, and then label each point with the land type?

Comment: You can also do a color-coded square for the rather tropical conditions you're interested in with boundaries delineating the percentage of area cover and color denoting the temperature and little annotations in the center of the subsquares with the usage kind.

Comment: @Twitch_City I don't think that makes much sense scientifically: two land cover types having similar or different percents are not ipso facto similar or different; also, % of land cover is not itself a forcing or influencing factor for temperature.

Comment: Good point. I've never worked with this kind of data before, and am unsure about what the OP is attempting to display.